# Only new folder in context menu on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

Is it normal for a fresh copy of Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit to only have "Folder" in the "New" item of the Explorer context menu? Do I need to add items manually? See below for a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does this happen in all drives/folders? Take a look at [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/215360/how-to-reenable-the-new-context-menu-items-for-an-administrator-when-right-cl) - seems to be a similar problem

Comment: It happens in all drives and folders. I'll have a look at that question. Thanks for the reply

Comment: The answer from your linked question has fixed the problem, I will quote it after 8 hours. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Copy the text below into a text file, save and rename to "context New restore"

Change the file extension from .txt to .reg, once this is done right click on the reg file and select merge. Reboot may be required.

This should restore all default items to the "New" menu

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bmp\ShellNew]
"ItemName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,72,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,6d,00,73,00,70,00,61,00,69,00,6e,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,\
  2d,00,35,00,39,00,34,00,31,00,34,00,00,00
"NullFile"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.contact\ShellNew]
"command"=hex(2):22,00,25,00,70,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,\
  69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,\
  00,20,00,4d,00,61,00,69,00,6c,00,5c,00,57,00,61,00,62,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\
  65,00,22,00,20,00,2f,00,43,00,72,00,65,00,61,00,74,00,65,00,43,00,6f,00,6e,\
  00,74,00,61,00,63,00,74,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00
"iconpath"=hex(2):25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,\
  6c,00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,\
  00,4d,00,61,00,69,00,6c,00,5c,00,77,00,61,00,62,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,31,00,00,00
"MenuText"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,43,00,6f,00,6d,00,6d,00,6f,00,6e,00,50,00,72,00,\
  6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,5c,00,77,00,61,00,62,00,33,00,32,00,72,00,\
  65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,31,00,30,00,32,00,30,00,33,\
  00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.docx\Word.Document.12\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jnt\jntfile\ShellNew]
"ItemName"=hex(2):40,00,22,00,25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,\
  46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,\
  00,73,00,20,00,4a,00,6f,00,75,00,72,00,6e,00,61,00,6c,00,5c,00,4a,00,6f,00,\
  75,00,72,00,6e,00,61,00,6c,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,2c,00,2d,00,33,\
  00,30,00,37,00,39,00,00,00
"FileName"="journal.jnt"
"Command"=hex(2):22,00,25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,\
  69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,\
  00,20,00,4a,00,6f,00,75,00,72,00,6e,00,61,00,6c,00,5c,00,4a,00,6f,00,75,00,\
  72,00,6e,00,61,00,6c,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,2f,00,6e,00,20,\
  00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew]
"Handler"="{ceefea1b-3e29-4ef1-b34c-fec79c4f70af}"
"IconPath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,\
  31,00,36,00,37,00,36,00,39,00,00,00
"ItemName"="@shell32.dll,-30397"
"MenuText"="@shell32.dll,-30318"
"NullFile"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew\Config]
"DontRename"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pptx\PowerPoint.Show.12\ShellNew]
"FileName"="pwrpnt12.pptx"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Briefcase\ShellNew]
"IconPath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,79,00,6e,00,63,00,75,00,69,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,30,00,00,00
"ItemName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,73,00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,\
  2d,00,36,00,34,00,39,00,33,00,00,00
"Directory"=""
"Handler"="{85BBD920-42A0-1069-A2E4-08002B30309D}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Briefcase\ShellNew\Config]
"IsFolder"=""
"NoExtension"=""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Open the Registry and go to 
   `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*the file extension of the file you want to add to the menu*`
   (I'll use .docx as an example)
2. Create a key of which the name corresponds with the application that should be used. In this case that would be **Word.Document.12**.
3. Under that key, create a new key called `ShellNew`. 
   In `ShellNew`, create a string value called `NullFile` and leave the value-field empty.
4. You might have to restart explorer.exe or log the user off and on again after this.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed my security settings for the partition and now everything's okay.

*Properties → Security → Advanced → Change Permissions*

Set full access to all of them.

Comment: "Security" and "full access" are completely opposed...